# Java Program print numbers in range with conditions

Tags: java, loops, range

I'm a little lost with a a loop exercise, I have to print the numbers in a range  that follow the following condition:

1. ***Each number of a number must be the same as the sum of the numbers of his left***. For example:

   - 112 will be printed, because all of it's components are the sum of the numbers of his left.
   - 101 will not be printed, because the 0 isn't the sum of the numbers of his left.
2. ***If the sum is greater than 9, tens will be discarded***:

   - 5500 will be printed.

I have this code:

```
public class Program {

    /**
     * Prints the list of numbers from desde to hasta such that the righmost
     * digit of the sum of previous digits equals current digit, and that
     * happens for all digits
     * 
     * Prints a 2nd line with as many underscores as characters contains the 1st
     * line
     * 
     * If desde < 10 o the parameters make no sense, prints Err __
     * 
     * 
     * @param desde
     *            int from (included)
     * @param hasta
     *            int to (included)
     * @return void
     */
    public static void sumDigitsConsecutius(int desde, int hasta) {

        int suma = 0;
        int numeroSuma = 0;

        for (int i = desde; i <= hasta; i++) {

            int longitud = lenght(i);
            int posicion = longitud - 1;
            int contador = 0;

            for (double numComparar = posicioNumber(i, posicion); posicion > 0; posicion--) {

                numeroSuma = posicioNumber(i, lenght(i));
                suma = suma + numeroSuma;
                if (suma != numComparar) {
                    break;
                } else {

                    numeroSuma = posicioNumber(i, (lenght(i) - 1));
                    contador++;
                }
            }

            if (contador == longitud - 1) {
                System.out.println(i);
            }

        }

    }

    /**
     * With this method i can calculate the length of a number
     */

    public static int lenght(int numero) {

        int contador = 0;

        while (numero > 0) {
            contador++;
            numero = numero / 10;
        }
        return contador;

    }

    public static int posicioNumber(int numero, int posicio) {

        // Digit of n in position p
        int x;
        // Remove right digits from position p.
        x = numero / (int) Math.pow(10, posicio - 1);
        // Get the last digit.
        x = x % 10;
        return x;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        sumDigitsConsecutius(80, 120);
    }
}
```

I created 2 additional methods, the first one calculates the length of a number and the second one the value of a number depending on the position.

Any ideas?

Comment: This isn't a site to dump homework and have people help you with it. Please ask a specific question

Comment: I just wanted to know why this program dosn't print anything, i don't see where it fails

Comment: It's really difficult to read your code when it's not in English. You should see if there's a SE site for your language.

Comment: Have you check your logic by debug the program ??

Comment: Can you check the provided answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I go through your code and identify some of the issues on the logic and I have correct them go through following code and check whether you can understand the changers. (Keep it mind since your variables not in English it was quite difficult to understand your logic). How ever below code will give the result you required.

```
public class Program {

/**
 * Prints the list of numbers from desde to hasta such that the righmost
 * digit of the sum of previous digits equals current digit, and that
 * happens for all digits
 * 
 * Prints a 2nd line with as many underscores as characters contains the 1st
 * line
 * 
 * If desde < 10 o the parameters make no sense, prints Err __
 * 
 * 
 * @param desde
 *            int from (included)
 * @param hasta
 *            int to (included)
 * @return void
 */
public static void sumDigitsConsecutius(int desde, int hasta) {

    int suma = 0;
    int numeroSuma = 0;

    for (int i = desde; i <= hasta; i++) {

        int longitud = lenght(i);
        int contador = 0;

        suma = 0;
        for (int posicion = longitud; posicion > 0; posicion--) {


            numeroSuma = posicioNumber(i, posicion);
            if (posicion !=longitud && suma != numeroSuma) {
                break;
            } else {
                contador++;
            }
            suma = suma + numeroSuma;

            //If the sum greater than 9 then position discarded 
            if(suma>=10){
                suma=suma%10;
            }
        }

        if (contador == longitud ) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }

    }

}

/**
 * With this method i can calculate the length of a number
 */

public static int lenght(int numero) {

    int contador = 0;

    while (numero > 0) {
        contador++;
        numero = numero / 10;
    }
    return contador;

}

public static int posicioNumber(int numero, int posicio) {

    // Digit of n in position p
    int x;
    // Remove right digits from position p.
    x = numero / (int) Math.pow(10, posicio - 1);
    // Get the last digit.
    x = x % 10;
    return x;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    sumDigitsConsecutius(1, 1000);
}


}
```

For the above class it will give below output (Number range 1-1000)

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
11
22
33
44
55
66
77
88
99
112
224
336
448
550
662
774
886
998
```